# Running cruise control.net under different credentials

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

So I have one part of my build that requires domain rights and does file copying.

Another part of my build runs some program that requires the user to interact with the desktop which seem to be only accomplish able by the system account.

What is the best way to work around these two items?  At the moment it seems like I can only do one or the other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to do `net use s: \\<share path> <password> /user:<domain user> /savecred`, which will allow your system account to impersonate the domain user for the share connection.

Another way is to use the `runas.exe /user:<your domain user> /savecred <program>`. Note that this would require someone running `runas` to enter the domain user password form the context of your CC.Net user. You can do this by opening a console as the system account (there are numerous articles on this topic, because of CC.Net SVN integration) and manually running `runas /savecred` and providing the password.

An alternative is to create a separate COM service that runs as the domain account and have a command line tool that CC.Net invokes that call that service.

Yet another alternative would be to have the CC.Net schedule an immediate task running as the domain user. You can use `schtasks.exe` to do that. You'll need an xml file with the task definition, which will need to contain the domain user name and password.