# MSB3491: Could not write lines to file cruise control

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, clearcase

I am receiving the below error when I'm trying to build the solution file from MSBUILD.
I'm building the solution file  from ClearCase integration stream .

When I do the same from a different system it works fine on the integration stream.

I have tried creating and writing the file into the N/W drive & it works fine.

But when I build it through **CruiseControl** it is throwing the following error.

```
 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets(3041,9): 
 error MSB3491: 
 Could not write lines to file "obj\DAL.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt".  
 Access to the path 'M:\yj73_SRDV3G_Proj_01_00_int\SRM_COMP\SRDV3G_Project\CRDB_V3\Application_Source\DAL\obj\DAL.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt' is denied.
```

Answer (score 2):

Two usual causes:

- The `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable is incorrectly set and don't reference the primary or secondary group of the Vob `\SRM_COMP` (see `cleartool descr -l vob:\SRM_COMP` for a list of those groups)
- The path is somehow not selected by the current config spec.
  It is best to do a cleartool ls in `M:\yj73_SRDV3G_Proj_01_00_int\SRM_COMP\SRDV3G_Project\CRDB_V3\Application_Source\DAL` to see how ClearCase displays `obj`.

The [OP user1383839](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1383839/user1383839) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13050026/6309) not using the right account for the [Build Loop](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/index.html), which means it didn't benefit from the right environment variable, hence the "access denied" message.
Or you can also "runas" the project as a different user (see "[Running cruise control.net under different credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016959/running-cruise-control-net-under-different-credentials)")

Comment: So what is the solution for this ? How can i see the CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP. I can build the solution file from different system on the integration stream

Comment: @user1383839 sorry for the delay, did you manage to check the `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`? You add a step in your CruiseControl job in order to display it. The key is to make sure the job, as executed by CruiseControl, has the correct right in order to access this dynamic view.

Comment: It is able to get the solution from the clear case , but when it is trying to create the obj folder in clear case , it is not able to write under that.

Comment: @user1383839 so what does a '`cleartool ls in M:\yj73_SRDV3G_Proj_01_00_int\SRM_COMP\SRDV3G_Project\CRDB_V3\Application_Source\DAL`' returns? And is your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` correctly set?

Comment: CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP is set to ccuser and we dont find any issue with that

Comment: @user1383839 ok but is set when the CruiseControl job is running (ie: is it running with the logged on account, or is it running as a system account?). Is that variable set for the "System environment variables" or the "Users environment variable" (assuming a windows server here). And is that group '`ccusers`' part of the primary or secondary groups of the vob?

Answer (score 0):

This issue got Fixed !:)

I was using the local account Previous

you need to go to the properties of the cruise control and change the account it is being used.

Comment: Excellent. I have updated my answer to reflect your conclusion. As I had initially stated, not having the right environment variable will trigger that error.